VS Code and Liberty: DataSource defined in server.xml not found by server
Here is my server.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>json-1.0</feature>     
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>   
        <feature>distributedMap-1.0</feature>
        <feature>webCache-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" />

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
    
    <!--Data Config-->
    
    <library id="DB2JCC4Lib">
        <fileset dir="C:/Munka/SQLLIB/java_new" includes="db2jcc4.jar"/>
    </library>
    
    <jdbcDriver id="DB2JDBCDriver" libraryRef="DB2JCC4Lib" javax.sql.DataSource="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource"/>
    
    
    <connectionManager id="defaultConnectionManager" maxConnectionsPerThread="10" purgePolicy="EntirePool"/>
    
    <dataSource transactional="false" id="sss_ha_csn_DS" jndiName="jdbc/sss_ha_csn_DS" connectionManagerRef="defaultConnectionManager" jdbcDriverRef="DB2JDBCDriver" type="javax.sql.XADataSource">
        <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="SYSSUPT" user="RETRACTED" password="RETRACTED" portNumber="50000" serverName="localhost"/>
    </dataSource>

    <!-- Default SSL configuration enables trust for default certificates from the Java runtime --> 
    <ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" trustDefaultCerts="true" />
</server>

My application has the following line:
DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.lookup(dataBasePoolURLStr);
The application establishes the DataSource correctly when I am running Liberty server from Eclipse.
However when I want to run the same config in VS Code I get the following error:
ERROR com.ibm.esup.css.common.dataaccess.CSSDAOFactory - getDataSource(String): Error = javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Intermediate context does not exist: jdbc/sss_ha_csn_DS

Any advice is welcome!

Eclipse [IDE] launches and runs Liberty [application] server, correct? How are you launching Liberty when you try to run your application from VS Code?

To add on the last comment, how are you launching Liberty and how are you providing the server.xml config in VS Code?  E.g. are you using one of the Liberty Maven/Gradle plugins to copy it from your project source?

In VS Code I installed Liberty Tools from VS Marketplace. This added a Liberty Dashboard to VS Code. My web application project automatically appeared in the Dashboard after installation and there is a Start option there. I am using Maven to compile my Java WAR files and then a single EAR file out of them. When I click Start in the Dashboard, I can see the Maven build starting and finishing in the console. My server.xml however was never supplied by Maven, that only deals with the Java code.

After I first started the application I noticed a target folder appear in my project folder which contained a server.xml file. I did not figure out where the server.xml got populated from. It was very basic, nearly empty. However I did confirm that making changes to the server.xml file in this location changes the behavior of the server when started, so I started to edit it here.

Looks like you are missing jdbc and jndi features. Add them to the server.xml and see if it makes any difference.

Adding the JNDI feture had no effect.
Adding JDBC solved the issue. Thank you!

I just wanted to give some background on where the server.xml came from that showed up in the target folder. You can provide a server.xml in the src/main/liberty/config folder of your project and it will get copied over. If none is provided, a default server.xml gets generated by Liberty when the server is created. Any changes you make to the file in the target folder can get overwritten when other server goals are run or if mvn clean is run. You can also point to a server.xml in a different location with the plugin configuration serverXmlFile parameter.

Hi Onac, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See can I answer my own question..
, Just a reminder :)

Including the JDBC feature solved the problem:
<feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>

Adding JDBC could solve this problem.
<feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>

